# SQL use CTE and PIVOT to make Calender of Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case, common-table-expression

I am trying to build a CTE to give me a Calendar of the days between a start date and `GETDATE()` i.e the number of Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc.

I have a case statement which has conditions that need to be met before the calendar count can complete

My effective start date if is a 1 2 or 3 will add the number of days to it using Date-Add and should do this continuously until `GETDATE()`.

I Know i need to use the pivot but seem to be having a lot of trouble getting the PIVOT to work with the CTE,

```
WITH CTE 
AS (
  select MR.ContractId B2,Name A1, EffectiveStartDate A ,swd2.Id B
  FROM [VES.DES].dbo.MasterRound mr LEFT JOIN [VES.DES].dbo.ScheduledWeekDay swd2
                ON MR.RoundRecurrenceId = SWd2.Id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
            B2,A1,
            CASE    
            When B = 2 Then DATEADD(D,+7,A) 
            When B = 1 Then DATEADD(D,+1,A)
            When B = 3 Then DATEADD(D,+14,A) END AS A, B

  FROM CTE WHERE A < GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.B2 = '12' 
AND DATEPART(m, A) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

The output I want in the end is

```
NAME(A1), Month, MON, Tues, WED, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun   
---------------------------------------------------    
FW1        JAN    4     3      4    5    3   4    2
FW3        FEB    4     5      4    4    4   4    5
```

Any help would be great as i appreciate this is quite complicated

Comment: Why don't you create a CTE calender table first, and use that table in  the more complex part. I did not study your syntax fully, but it seems you are doing everything in the first part of the CTE and then select everything in the 2nd part. Which makes it a complex union, with a repeat of the same joins. If you do the joins in the 2nd part, you only have to do them once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip i will be trying that now,

Comment: Thanks Wietze i have based on your comment created a totally different query which should give me the same result, however i am now stuck on the pivot so if you can help we with that it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier with the CTE combo to not use PIVOT.

Use a GROUP BY like

```
SELECT
A1,
SUM(
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, A) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Sunday
,
SUM(
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, A) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Monday

FROM CTE

WHERE CTE.B2 = '12' 
AND DATEPART(m, A) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
option (maxrecursion 0)

GROUP BY A1
```

Comment: Hi I am not entirely sure i understand, what do i do about my case statement and Date Add function. i need those in there before i convert the date into date name, at the moment if i use date name with date add i get a conversion date or time from character string. Thanks in advance

Comment: I changed the syntax in my answer. You can still use the filter. Let me know what is wrong with the solution, if it is not yet your answer.

Comment: Hi Wietze i got it working now had to play around with the syntax a bit to get it done but with a little help and modification managed to get it to work, thanks a bunch much appreciated